# C#: Changing picture in form, using picture from resourses

Tags: c#

I have 7 pictures in resources, named 1.jpg, 2.jpg ect..

Then in code I have generated int skaicius, which has value 5...

Now I need on button push avent change the image to `skaicius + ".jpg"` and use image from imported resources

It's something like that I think

```
 pictureBox2.ImageLocation = kauliukas + ".jpg";
```

But It's supposed to load image from local dir as I know... SO how to load it from resources?

Comment: you can directly do like this pictureBox2.Image = Resources.myImage;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you import your pictures to the Resources (resx) file, the extensions are lost, and for example "ThisPicture.jpg" would be accessed through Properties.Resources.ThisPicture.

Which effectively means you can do the following on your PictureBox:

```
pictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.PictureName
```

Where PictureName is the name of the actual resources according to your Resources file.